# I am having trouble with using user input in control flow statements- Java

Tags: java, eclipse

I am just trying to create a simple program using Eclipse IDE that obtains user input, which will be their order, obtained using BufferedReader for either a hamburger, fries, or whatever else, which will be assumed as a drink for now. Then, using conditional statements, I will output the cost of that item to the user, the hamburger being 4.50, the fries being 3.00, and the drink or any other input 1.50:

```
public class Menu {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
       //double totalCost;
       double cost;
       //String order = "fries";
       BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
       System.out.println("Please enter your order: ");
       String order = input.readLine();
       System.out.println("You ordered a: " + order);
       if (order == "hamburger"){
           cost = 4.50;
       } else if (order == "fries"){
           cost = 3.00;
       } else {
          cost = 1.50;
       }
       System.out.println("Cost: " + cost);
   }
}
```

The trouble I am having has to do with the order variable, which stores the user input:
String order = input.readLine();

It seems that I am successfully able to store the user input into this String variable, and then output it using the debug statement below it. However, when it comes to my if-then-else statements, it is not evaluated properly, and it automatically goes to the ending else statement, and outputs 1.5 as the cost (I will worry about formatting later, I'm just trying to get the functionality for now).

I even tried putting Sysout in each conditional block as in:

```
if (order == "hamburger"){
    cost = 4.50;
    System.out.println("Cost: " + cost);
}

else if (order == "fries"){
    cost = 3.00;
    System.out.println("Cost: " + cost);
}
else{
    cost = 1.50;
    System.out.println("Cost: " + cost);
}
```

..and I still obtain the same results where it says Cost: 1.5. Again, I will worry about formatting later.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't compare `String` objects with `==`. Instead, use the `.equals()` method.

```
if ("hamburger".equals(order)){
    cost = 4.50;
    System.out.println("Cost: " + cost);
}
else if ("fries".equals(order)){
    cost = 3.00;
    System.out.println("Cost: " + cost);
} else{
    cost = 1.50;
    System.out.println("Cost: " + cost);
}
```

What you have to remember, is that `==` compares whether the two variables point to the one and the same address in the memory, whether `.equals()` compares their values.

Use `==` only to compare primitives or enumerations.

Answer (score 1):

You want to test using equals, not ==

```
if (order.equals("hamburger")) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Never compare objects with `==` (except enums). `==` tests if the two expressions refer to the same object. Use `equals()` instead, which tests if the two expressions refer to objects that are functionally equal (i.e. if the Strings have the same characters in this case)

Answer (score 1):

The operator `==` in Java compares if the objects are the same, not the String itself. You should use `equals()` instead.